# Making proxy available on remote server through ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I know I can use ssh tunneling to create a "proxy" on my machine so that I can make all the traffic generated locally go through a remote server. Like this:

```
$ ssh -D 12345 myuser@remote_ssh_server
```

But what about if I need to create a "proxy" on the remote server, so that all the traffic that I send it will go through my local machine? Is this possible with ssh?

Essentially, I want to use my local internet connection with some specific commands to run remotely, as the server does not have direct access to the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is one port and host at a time. For example, to forward traffic from remote:8001 to intraserver:80,

```
ssh -R 8001:intraserver:80 myuser@remote
```

But if you want to forward all traffic from remote, and you have an ssh server running on your local host,

```
ssh -R 2200:localhost:22 myuser@remote ssh -D 10800 -p 2200 localhost
```

Unwrapping that:

- `-R 2200:localhost:22` sets up a forward from remote:2200 to localhost:22.
- `ssh -p 2200 localhost` runs ssh on remote, to connect to remote:2200, and so back to localhost:22 (tunneled over the first ssh connection).
- `-D 10800` tunnels SOCKS from remote:10800, over the connection from remote back to localhost.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I couldn't quite get it to work though. After running the commands I'm back on ``localhost`` and ``wget http://www.google.com`` is able to retrieve a file, but if I ssh back to ``remote`` and try to get the same address through the proxy with ``wget http://www.google.com -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=localhost:10800
`` I get only the following message on the output: ``Proxy request sent, awaiting response... No data received.``. Any thoughts?

Comment: BTW, one thing that I've noticed is that final ``... localhost:2200`` part, that has actually have to be ``localhost -p 2200`` for my ssh client version.

Comment: Nevermind, the issue is with wget, that doens't seem to support SOCKS all that well. This, on the other hand, runs flawlessly: ``curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:10800 http://www.google.com/``

Comment: Good! Right, `ssh -D` creates a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy.