# How can I adapt this technique of using a proxy (in firefox) to wget and yum ?

Tags: firewall, proxy, internet

I work in a large organization where some people have extremely restricted internet access and some are given a fairly large amount of freedom. The way my organization manages this is by running a proxy server with minimized restrictions and giving access to the people who need it.

However, I am not sure if I understand this way of setting up a prozy. I am explaining the technique below:

There is a machine to which I `ssh -D 9999 username@proxymachine.XYZdomain.com` 
It prompts me for a password and then I log into it and I leave that terminal running ...

then I move to firefox and do the following settings:

[image]

And then I am able to use the proxy.

My question is this: How can I use this same proxy to run wget and yum. Both yum and wget have their conf files, but they have options for http_proxy. This peculiar way of using a proxy that we have; can it be "adapted" to wget ? to yum ? if yes, can you please tell em the way to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making proxy available on remote server through ssh tunneling](http://serverfault.com/questions/624685/making-proxy-available-on-remote-server-through-ssh-tunneling)

Comment: @HBruijn not really. The questions are quite different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wget you need to define an environment variable with the your proxy:

```
export SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:9999
wget http://example.com
```

I don't use yum, but apparently you need to define the proxy in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
proxy=socks5h://localhost:9999
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43654/how-to-use-socks-proxy-with-yum

For info on using other programs with SOCKS a simple Google search for "program with socks proxy" should provide plenty of information.